# Python - add trigger words that will trigger POST request

Tags: python, post, discord

I'm trying to make a Discord webhook poster which will make a post request whenever a file updates (adds a line) with a specific set of words.

Let's say the new line has "TRIGGER WORD", then it will trigger the post request. I have come to making the service read the file but don't know how to create the trigger section

```
import requests
import schedule
import time

link = 'webhook link'


def job():
    file = open('/root/rak/b7/client.log','r').read()

    payload={'content': '@everyone '}
    r = requests.post(link, data=payload)

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Here the payload will contain everything in the line plus the `@everyone` thing. I can't figure out how to make it do so.

Also about the file; It updates every second (adds 1-2 lines). The specific trigger word(s) might be in any one of the new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to keep track of the size of the file the previous time you ran `job()`. Removing that much will give you the new portion. This will get slower as the file gets bigger but depending on your situation may be fine.

```
oldSize = 0


def job():
    global oldSize

    fileContents = open('/root/rak/b7/client.log','r').read()
    newSize = len(fileContents)

    newFileContents = fileContents[oldSize : ] #delete the old stuff

    addedLines = newFileContents.split('\n') #split by lines

    for line in addedLines:
        if line.find('TRIGGER WORDS') != -1:
            payload={'content': '@everyone ' + line}
            r = requests.post(link, data=payload)

    oldSize = newSize #make oldSize have correct value next time
```

Comment: This worked but how do I add multiple trigger words? Like for example the POST request will only get triggered when both the trigger words are present in the lines

For example;
The trigger will only go off when Two trigger words are present in the line (other words may be in between those two triggers)

> New line;
"TRIGGER1 SOMEWORDSINBETWEEN TRIGGER2"

Comment: Do you need both trigger words present? Is it exactly 2 words?

Comment: Yeah both in the same line

Comment: Try `if line.find('TRIGGER') != -1 and line.find('WORDS') != -1:`

Comment: I messed up the : after the second !=

And yeah it worked!